# Laptop waking up when docked

Tags: 22.04, suspend, dell, thunderbolt

My laptop wakesup on it's own when suspended. It only happens when docked.
I'm running ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Precision 5560 and WD19 dell dock.

I suppose the dock is waking up the laptop.  How can I diagnose and fix it ?